How to optimize random path generation with checkpoints and collision detection
I'm looking for a way to generate a random path based on midi note onsets (timing points) for a simulation/game.
I will briefly explain how it works for context:
I'm working on a simulation type game where a square bounces around a procedurally generated map based on a given .mid file from which it extracts the note onsets.
Right now the map is being generated as follows using backtracking (simplified example):

Given a list of note onsets.
Start with the square at its initial position and direction.
For each note onset:
Move the square until the current time reaches the note onset.
Check for collisions with previously visited (bounced off of) checkpoints.
Occasionally change the square's direction by random chance.
If a collision is detected or no valid path is found, backtrack:

Undo the last moves and try a different direction.
If necessary, reverse the direction of the square and try again.


If the square reaches the next note onset without collision, continue to the next onset.
Repeat the above steps recursively, exploring different paths and backtracking when needed.
Finally, process the path to remove overlaps and merge adjacent areas.

Important:

The squares only possible directions are diagonally so north-east, south-east, south-west and north-west.
The square moves at a constant speed.
The checkpoints are basically just tiny rectangles (see screenshot and sketch).
As you might imagine this is not very fast and/or memory efficient.

I was wondering if there are any better ways of doing this (algorithm wise for example)?
I was personally thinking something using a grid, this would change how things work but I'm fine with that.
NOTE: A random look to the map is important, it cannot just go bouncing on to the right until the last note for example.


